# Force impagination sequence

Tags: floats, positioning

I want to force my document to be in this order:

- text
- tabular
- image

This group is repeated some times; as you can imagine the compiler mix the elements (e.g. text1, tab1, text2, tab2, img1, img2).

How can I force the correct order?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text help you?

Comment: or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned?

Comment: Or this reference answer regarding floats: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/8344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [`endfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package, especially at sections 3.4 and 7 of its manual.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers,tablesfirst]{endfloat}
\renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vspace{\floatsep}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\centering
(Tabular material)
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
(Tabular material)
\caption{Another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```