# float placement at the end of the document

Tags: floats, positioning, endfloat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force impagination sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49483/force-impagination-sequence)
>   [How can I remove the figures from a draft of my document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50904/how-can-i-remove-the-figures-from-a-draft-of-my-document)

Is there a way I can specify an option to tell TeX to place all of the floats I have in my document at the end of the document? Specifically I am inserting them currently where I will need them eventually but for the working paper phase I would like to have them all just follow the text of my document.  Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe the `endfloat` package would help. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49483/force-impagination-sequence

Comment: I think that your question is covered by this one, specifically by the first answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50904/11002 Please let us know if it is what you are asking for, or specify your question.

Comment: thank you both, the endfloat package is what I needed. Should I close this question or does one of you want to place your comment in the answer?

Comment: @Alex We'll close the question without answers. It will be useful anyway, because whoever has a similar problem may find this one which will point to the other question.