# Figures Grouped at the End

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

A requirement for a paper I'm writing is that all figures occur at the end of the document, with one figure per page, and with a page of figure captions preceding the pages of figures.

Is there any way to automate this from what I have? (That is, figures normally interspersed in the document with `\caption`'s and `\label`'s inside the `\begin{figure}` environment)

If not, (that is, if I would need to move the figures around) what would be a good TeX-approved way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). The `endfloat` package may help: [see this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49483/force-impagination-sequence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply load the [`endfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package; a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=9cm]{geometry}% just to reduce the paper height for the example
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{endfloat}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image1}
\caption{Test figure one}
\label{fig:testa}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{image2}
\caption{Test figure two}
\label{fig:testb}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is a four page document with the desired requirements (floats at the end, one image per page and and with a page of figure captions preceding the pages of figures):

[image]

If you would rather not have the notes the package leaves in the text (i.e., "[Figure 1 about here.]"), use the `nomarkers` option. By default, the package moves the contents of all the `figure` and `table` environments; if you only want to move the figures, you should use the `figuresonly` option.

So, to suppress the notes and move only the figures, you can load the package in the following way:

```
\usepackage[nomarkers,figuresonly]{endfloat}
```

The demo option for graphicx simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do not use that option in your actual document.